# Error trying to use datasource in SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Does anyone know how to resolve the issue when presented with the following error message when trying to select a datasource for a report in SQL Server Analysis Services?

`Non-Windows user credentials were supplied for a non-http connection to Analysis Services. The Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services data extension requires Windows Integrated Security unless connecting via http or https.`

Comment: The answer depends on your configuration - protocols, whether SQL Server is local/remote, in Active Directory/Workgroup, on versions/editions of operating system and SQL Server, etc. and how they are configured.  

SSAS supports only Windows Integrated Authentication.  

Are you using SSAS datasource in SSRS?

Comment: So as it turns out I just wasn't checking "Use as windows credentials when connecting to the data source"

Comment: That was my first impulse to answer but, then, I found that this really depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on configuration - protocols, whether SQL Server is local/remote, in Active Directory/Workgroup, on versions/editions of operating system and SQL Server, etc. and how they are configured.

SSAS supports only Windows Integrated Authentication.

The topic starter devlife answered that he should have checked ""Use as windows credentials when connecting to the data source".
I answer it because I want to have this post in my lists and comments will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I search about 3 days and hope this answer help someone :
There are an option on SSRS for each report:

[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sXeD.png)

If u set there your information. this error will be fixed.